# Unable to receive Push Notifications on android/ios devices

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting following error while running the [event source-based notifications sample project](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/) for MobileFirst Platform 6.3.

I am not receiving any Push Notifications to my android or ios devices.

MobileFirst Development Server Console Shows:

```
[ERROR   ] submitNotification >> userId :: Raj, text :: Welcome, Eager
to Have Engagement with you [project PushNotifications]  
[ERROR   ] B4 notifying============{"APNS":{"badge":1,"alert":"Welcome, Eager to Have Engagement with you","payload":{"custom":"data"},"sound":"","actionKey":null},"GCM":{"alert":"Welcome,
Eager to Have Engagement with you","badge":1,"payload":{"custom":"data"}},"SMS":{"text":"Welcome, Eager to Have Engagement with
you"},"MPNS":{"raw":{"payload":{"custom":"data"}},"toast":null,"tile":{"title":"Welcome,
Eager to Have Engagement with you","count":1}}} [project
PushNotifications]  
[ERROR   ] Notified to device======================={"userId":"Raj","state":{}} [project
PushNotifications]  
[ERROR   ] Couldn't connect to APNS server Connection timed out: connect
```

Answer (score 0):

Your network configuration is more than likely blocking a required address or port by the APNS servers (Apple's Push Notifications Service).

Verify that the following are accessible:

- Sandbox servers:
  gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
  feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196
- Production servers:
  gateway.push.apple.com:2195
  Feedback.push.apple.com:2196
- 1-courier.push.apple.com 5223
- the entire 17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple, so you can specify that range in your firewall rules